# Firebase Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
2016-08-22 18:34:50.108: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-08-22 18:34:50.106 YAKKO[4269:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ...)
2016-08-22 18:34:50.114: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2016-08-22 18:34:50.120: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.1.1
2016-08-22 18:34:50.125: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-08-22 18:34:50.144 YAKKO[4269:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-08-22 18:34:50.188 YAKKO[4269:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
```

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333177/cloud-messaging-handing-terminate-app). But I am still at a loss for how to fix it. Notifications aren't working and the only lead I have is the line: `Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"`

I have double checked that I uploaded the correct .p12 files into firebase. I have gone into Target->->Capabilities->Background Modes->`remote-notifications` and `ON`
I have double checked that my bundleID matches the GoogleService-Info.plist

Here is my AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FIRApp.configure()
        ....
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    print("DEVICE TOKEN = \(deviceToken)")
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
}
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    // NOTE: It can be nil here
    let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is that it should work without those last two methods, but I put them in there anyway (according to the print statements it doesn't look like they are being called).

I call registerForRemoteNotifications:

```
static func registerForNoties(){

    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

And I can see the deviceToken printed on the console. But I still get this FireBase issue. Any ideas of other things I can check?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No, I ended up giving up on Firebase for iOS and used PyAPNS (my backend is written on django/Python).

Answer (score 2):

I did try to build simple app based on Firebase/Quickstart-iOS example for iOS (Swift) and I had the same issue: `Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"`.

I was not able to receive notification while app was in background.
So, I've found solution that worked for me here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/103

Basically, I did add this method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            print("Handle push from background or closed" );
            print("%@", response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
        }
```

... and this line of code:

```
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Apparently, example written in Objective-C works fine, but example in Swift is missing some pieces of code and it doesn't work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Firebase/Core to v3.4.4, it fixed unexpected errors for me. Otherwise try to avoid calling `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`. After this call, you can't register the device anymore to push notifications. Also, try setting `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `NO` in your info.plist file. I think there are bugs with their method swizzling.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method you will get device token. And I can see the `deviceToken` printed on the console.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
{
     global.appdel.tokenRefreshNotification()
})
```

Comment: you should call this method where you first screen will appear. after appdelegate.

Comment: add this method inside viewdidload()