# Firebase Push Notification Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)" using Swift3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I receive the `(Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"` error when I close the app (Disconnected from FCM). It appears in the debug, but when the app is running and I send a notification, it just shows in the debug. Can any one help me to solve the problem?

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import UserNotifications
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseInstanceID
 import FirebaseMessaging


 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }



    // [END register_for_notifications]
    FIRApp.configure()

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)

    return true
}

// [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
// [END receive_message]
// [START refresh_token]
func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}
// [END refresh_token]
// [START connect_to_fcm]
func connectToFcm() {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
        return;
    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the InstanceID token.
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
     //FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
}

// [START connect_on_active]
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    connectToFcm()
}
// [END connect_on_active]
// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]
 }

 // [START ios_10_message_handling]
     @available(iOS 10, *)
   extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
  }
  // [END ios_10_message_handling]
  // [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
  extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the  foreground.
  func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage:   FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
  }
  }
```

Comment: Whether error delegate called when registering for APNS?

Comment: Just this error (Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)") appears in the debug.

Comment: Hi. Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37333177/4625829)?

Answer (score 0):

1.If you are using Xcode 8.2 and above.

Enable push notification entitlement in Capabilities. Please refer the attachment:

[image]

[image]

2. Please go to your firebase console and then find your project and go to its settings, there check in its cloud messaging tab and upload your .p12 certificate into that.

Comment: Thank you for your help but Iam do it all before asking my question and still the same error